# SQL Server table audit trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have two tables `Customers` and `AuditTable`. When I modify the `Customers` table, I need to insert a new record into the `AuditTable`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditTable]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StateBefore] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [StateAfter] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

I need to place an XML representation of `Customer` state into `StateBefore` and `StateAfter`, before and after update.

The `Customer` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [CreatedUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedUtc] [datetime] NULL,
    [Version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Customer] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,  
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] 
   ADD DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [CreatedUtc]
GO
```

I found the way how to get an xml representation of rows:

```
SELECT
    [State] = (SELECT *
               FROM dbo.Customer [Customer]
               WHERE [Customer].Id = cust.Id
               FOR XML AUTO
              )
FROM 
    dbo.Customer cust
```

It just for example. So in my trigger I need to create the xml representation of rows from `deleted` and `inserted` tables.

Here is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateCustomerTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Customer]
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customer 
    SET UpdatedUtc = GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE inserted.id = Customer.Id

    -- here I need to insert new records into AuditTable
END
```

So, how can I join two representations of `deleted` and `inserted` tables to correctly insert them into the `AuditTable`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great that you've found a solution already...

I was just thinking about something similar...

Your approach would take **two copies of the full record at any tiny change**. As I have to deal with tables with a lot of columns, some of them are BLOBs, this would not fit for me.

Well, I did not find an absolutely "clean" approach, but with the following you'll get an AuditLog with only the values which have changed acutally in a better to read style.

Maybe you like it:

#### Test.scenario

#### EDIT: Added support for `INSERT` and `DELETE` and `NULL` values.

Try it out:

```
CREATE TABLE AuditTest(TableSchema VARCHAR(250), TableName VARCHAR(250), AuditType VARCHAR(250),Content XML, LogDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE());
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(ID INT,Test1 VARCHAR(100),Test2 DATETIME,ModifyCounter INT DEFAULT 0,LastModified DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE());
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(ID,Test1,Test2) VALUES
 (1,'Test1',{d'2001-01-01'})
,(2,'Test2',{d'2002-02-02'});
```

--current content

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Test;
GO
```

--The trigger for the audit

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTestTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Test]
FOR UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted) RETURN;

   DECLARE @tp VARCHAR(10)=CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted) THEN 'upd'
                           ELSE CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted) THEN 'del' ELSE 'ins' END END;
   WITH UpdateableCTE AS
   (
    SELECT t.LastModified,t.ModifyCounter 
    FROM dbo.Test AS t
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON t.ID=i.ID
   )
   UPDATE UpdateableCTE SET LastModified=GETDATE()
                           ,ModifyCounter=ModifyCounter+1;

   SELECT * INTO #tmpInserted FROM inserted;
   SELECT * INTO #tmpDeleted FROM deleted;

   DECLARE @tableSchema VARCHAR(250)='dbo';
   DECLARE @tableName   VARCHAR(250)='Test';

   DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)=
   STUFF
   (
   (
    SELECT ',' + CASE WHEN @tp='upd' THEN 
           'CASE WHEN (i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']!=d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] ' +
           'OR (i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NULL AND d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NOT NULL) ' + 
           'OR (i.['+ COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NOT NULL AND d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NULL)) ' +
           'THEN ' ELSE '' END +
           '(SELECT ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS [@name]' + 
                         CASE WHEN @tp IN ('upd','del') THEN ',ISNULL(CAST(d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),N''##NULL##'') AS [@old]' ELSE '' END + 
                         CASE WHEN @tp IN ('ins','upd') THEN ',ISNULL(CAST(i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),N''##NULL##'') AS [@new] ' ELSE '' END + 
                  ' FOR XML PATH(''Column''),TYPE) ' + CASE WHEN @tp='upd' THEN 'END' ELSE '' END
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=@tableSchema AND TABLE_NAME=@tableName
    FOR XML PATH('')
   ),1,1,''
   );

    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=   
    'SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
    WITH ChangedColumns AS
    (
    SELECT COALESCE(i.ID,d.ID) AS ID
            ,Col.*  
    FROM #tmpInserted AS i
    FULL OUTER JOIN #tmpDeleted AS d ON i.ID=d.ID
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
        FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE
    ) AS Col([Column])
    )
    INSERT INTO AuditTest(TableSchema,TableName,AuditType,Content)
    SELECT ''' + @tableSchema + ''',''' + @tableName + ''',''' + @tp + '''
    ,(
    SELECT ''' + @tableSchema + ''' AS [@TableSchema]
            ,''' + @tableName + ''' AS [@TableName]
            ,''' + @tp + ''' AS [@ActionType]
    ,(
        SELECT ChangedColumns.ID AS [@ID]
        ,(
        SELECT x.[Column] AS [*],''''
        FROM ChangedColumns AS x WHERE x.ID=ChangedColumns.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE
        )
        FROM ChangedColumns
        FOR XML PATH(''Row''),TYPE
        )
    FOR XML PATH(''Changes'')
    );';

    EXEC (@cmd);

   DROP TABLE #tmpInserted;
   DROP TABLE #tmpDeleted;
END
GO
```

--Now let's test it with some operations:

```
UPDATE dbo.Test SET Test1='New 1' WHERE ID=1;
UPDATE dbo.Test SET Test1='New 1',Test2={d'2000-01-01'} ;
DELETE FROM dbo.Test WHERE ID=2;
DELETE FROM dbo.Test WHERE ID=99; --no affect
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(ID,Test1,Test2) VALUES
 (3,'Test3',{d'2001-03-03'})
,(4,'Test4',{d'2001-04-04'})
,(5,'Test5',{d'2001-05-05'});
UPDATE dbo.Test SET Test2=NULL; --all rows
DELETE FROM dbo.Test WHERE ID IN (1,3);
GO
```

--Check the final status

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Test;
SELECT * FROM AuditTest;
GO
```

--Clean up

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.AuditTest;
GO
```

#### Result of second action: UPDATE two rows

```
<Changes TableSchema="dbo" TableName="Test" ActionType="upd">
  <Row ID="2">
    <Column name="Test1" old="Test2" new="New 1" />
    <Column name="Test2" old="Feb  2 2002 12:00AM" new="Jan  1 2000 12:00AM" />
  </Row>
  <Row ID="1">
    <Column name="Test2" old="Jan  1 2001 12:00AM" new="Jan  1 2000 12:00AM" />
  </Row>
</Changes>
```

#### Result of `INSERT` action: three new rows

```
<Changes TableSchema="dbo" TableName="Test" ActionType="ins">
  <Row ID="5">
    <Column name="ID" new="5" />
    <Column name="Test1" new="Test5" />
    <Column name="Test2" new="May  5 2001 12:00AM" />
    <Column name="ModifyCounter" new="0" />
    <Column name="LastModified" new="Aug 18 2017  5:48PM" />
  </Row>
  <Row ID="4">
    <Column name="ID" new="4" />
    <Column name="Test1" new="Test4" />
    <Column name="Test2" new="Apr  4 2001 12:00AM" />
    <Column name="ModifyCounter" new="0" />
    <Column name="LastModified" new="Aug 18 2017  5:48PM" />
  </Row>
  <Row ID="3">
    <Column name="ID" new="3" />
    <Column name="Test1" new="Test3" />
    <Column name="Test2" new="Mar  3 2001 12:00AM" />
    <Column name="ModifyCounter" new="0" />
    <Column name="LastModified" new="Aug 18 2017  5:48PM" />
  </Row>
</Changes>
```

#### Result of last `DELETE` action

```
<Changes TableSchema="dbo" TableName="Test" ActionType="del">
  <Row ID="3">
    <Column name="ID" old="3" />
    <Column name="Test1" old="Test3" />
    <Column name="Test2" old="##NULL##" />
    <Column name="ModifyCounter" old="2" />
    <Column name="LastModified" old="Aug 18 2017  5:48PM" />
  </Row>
  <Row ID="1">
    <Column name="ID" old="1" />
    <Column name="Test1" old="New 1" />
    <Column name="Test2" old="##NULL##" />
    <Column name="ModifyCounter" old="3" />
    <Column name="LastModified" old="Aug 18 2017  5:48PM" />
  </Row>
</Changes>
```

Comment: Good solution! I like it but how about performace?

Comment: @AlexeyKu Well, any solution within a trigger will take somewhat away.  Depending on the size and complexitiy of a table your approach would get quite hungry too... It was actually necessary to introduce even more logic into this if you want to keep it generic and you might deal with different key types (multi-column!), One more point was the need to store the current user (Who is responsible?). Often this is an application driven concept... the biggest advantage of this: *When was the last modification to `FirstName` for ID=123?* Try to answer this with your *save everything* approach :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution. Here is the trigger code:

```
USE [ISContext]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[UpdateCustomerTrigger]    Script Date: 22.05.2016 10:40:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateCustomerTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Customer]
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customer SET UpdatedUtc = GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE inserted.id=Customer.Id

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AuditTable]
    SELECT
    StateBefore = 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM deleted [Customer]
        WHERE [Customer].Id = cust.Id
        FOR XML AUTO
    ),
    [StateAfter] =(
        SELECT *
        FROM inserted [Customer]
        WHERE [Customer].Id = cust.Id
        FOR XML AUTO
    )
    FROM inserted cust
END
```